# CASE statement SQL Between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to design a CASE Statement in SQL Server for a report parameter.
The report is presenting a timeframe against a set date. The expdate.

The parameter are sent in string format:

```
'All', '30', '31', '61', '91', '121', '150', '181+'
```

Trying to develop a `CASE` statement that will return:

```
WHERE expdate 
   CASE WHEN Timeframe = 'All' Then expdate  --All Dates
   CASE WHEN timeframe=30 THEN expdate between 0 and 30 --using datediff from today
   CASE WHEN timeframe=31 THEN expdate between 31 and 60 --using datediff 
   CASE WHEN timeframe=61 THEN expdate between 61 and 90 --using datediff
```

...

If there is a better way to do this than a `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause, I am all ears, but that's how I have done it in the past.

Thanks

Comment: How is the query being submitted? SSMS, a reporting tool, what?

Comment: So... does what you have work?  Are there any issues with it other than style?  If not then it would be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You can't do the CASE statement as shown.   What follows "THEN" must be a single value, not a logical operator like "between this and that".

Comment: How much control do you have over the database? Or how often do this. I think the best practice would be setup a Lookup or crosswalk table and just join on it. Then if you have changes/additions you can just update the table.

Comment: I would create start and stop dates (`DECLARE @start DATETIME = CASE WHEN @timeframe = '30' THEN GETDATE() - 30 WHEN ...` and `DECLARE @end DATETIME = CASE WHEN @timeframe = '30' THEN GETDATE() - 0 WHEN ...`) then use these dates in a simple `... WHERE date BETWEEN @start AND @end`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it with an (AND) OR (AND) structure, like this:

```
WHERE (timeframe='All')
OR (timeframe='30' AND expdate between 0 and 30)
OR (timeframe='31' AND expdate between 31 and 60)
OR (...
```

Comment: This works fine.  I actually knew this approach, but for some reason didn't have enough coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Not use case when but OR and AND using make condition.
I assume that expdate should be stored day. Like this

```
WHERE (Timeframe = 'All' AND expdate=expdate)  --All Dates
OR( timeframe=30 AND expdate between 0 and 30 )--using datediff from today
OR( timeframe=31 AND expdate between 31 and 60 )--using datediff 
OR (timeframe=61 AND expdate between 61 and 90) --using datediff
```